# Failed to center svg with flex

Tags: html, css

When trying to insert the svg to my page from the sprite sheet, the imbedded svg isn't placed at the center even after the properties to center it is applied. I am still a bit confused about this way of imbedding the svg and the role played by both **viewport** and **viewbox**.

```
// HTML
<svg class="card__icon">
  <use xlink:href="assets/sprite.svg#share"></use>
</svg>
// CSS
.card__icon {
  width:4rem;
  height:4rem;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
// Sprite sheet
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .sprite {
        display: none;
      }

      .sprite:target {
        display: inline;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g fill="none" class="sprite" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="share">
    <path d="M17.9359 15.9494C17.5431 15.9508 17.1547 16.0317 16.7939 16.187C16.4332 16.3424 16.1075 16.569 15.8365 16.8533L8.72737 13.2958C8.90225 12.7656 8.90225 12.1932 8.72737 11.6629L15.8481 8.0413C16.3582 8.57878 17.0498 8.90742 17.7887 8.96335C18.5275 9.01928 19.2608 8.79849 19.8459 8.34391C20.4311 7.88932 20.8263 7.23341 20.9548 6.50367C21.0832 5.77393 20.9358 5.02248 20.5411 4.39539C20.1464 3.76829 19.5326 3.31035 18.8191 3.11058C18.1056 2.9108 17.3433 2.98346 16.6803 3.31443C16.0174 3.6454 15.5012 4.21104 15.232 4.9014C14.9629 5.59177 14.9601 6.35754 15.2241 7.04987L8.17334 10.6365C7.79254 10.1708 7.27703 9.83425 6.69747 9.67302C6.1179 9.51179 5.50266 9.53375 4.93607 9.73591C4.36948 9.93806 3.87928 10.3105 3.53267 10.8022C3.18606 11.2939 3 11.8807 3 12.4823C3 13.0839 3.18606 13.6707 3.53267 14.1624C3.87928 14.6541 4.36948 15.0265 4.93607 15.2287C5.50266 15.4308 6.1179 15.4528 6.69747 15.2916C7.27703 15.1303 7.79254 14.7938 8.17334 14.3281L15.2066 17.868C15.0878 18.1871 15.0266 18.5248 15.0258 18.8653C15.0258 19.442 15.1968 20.0058 15.5172 20.4853C15.8377 20.9648 16.2931 21.3386 16.8259 21.5593C17.3587 21.78 17.945 21.8377 18.5106 21.7252C19.0763 21.6127 19.5959 21.335 20.0037 20.9272C20.4115 20.5194 20.6892 19.9998 20.8017 19.4342C20.9142 18.8685 20.8565 18.2822 20.6358 17.7494C20.4151 17.2166 20.0413 16.7612 19.5618 16.4408C19.0823 16.1204 18.5185 15.9494 17.9418 15.9494H17.9359Z" fill="currentColor"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: You mean the center of the page or the center of `card__icon`? if it's `card__icon`, you already set a limited size, so it's will be the center of `4rem x 4rem`

Comment: Hi, I meant the center of the **card__icon**. It only aligns to the top left corner of the **card__icon**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you well, I think you have to apply flex to the parent of the svg element. For example if your SVG is inside a div like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```

Then you need to apply flex like this:

```
div.container {
  display flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: It works. It seems to me that the viewport(width and height) has to be first set on **svg** to align with viewbox(0 0 24 24). After that, we wrap it up with a container to center the svg as **flex item**. My question still remains. Why we couldn't directly center it by setting the flex property on **svg**??

Comment: The flex applys to the children not to element itself

Comment: I think I know what you meant. **SVG** is like a canvas to display image on so we cannot directly apply flex on it to center the image. Instead, we should see the canvas and the image on it as a whole and then center the **SVG** (canvas) itself. Is my understanding on this correct?